# c# datatable select last row on a speicfic condition

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a datatable has data like this format

........ IVR........

.........IVR........

**.........IVR........**

.........City1......

.........City1......

**.........City1......**

.........City2......

.........City2......

**.........City2......**

I want to take the last row of each value. in order words, the rows that are bold now

The challenge is that i wan these **three** rows in a datatable. I tried to search on internet but i didn't know what is the name of this feature. could you help me please

Comment: Do you need `GroupBy`?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev no i don't think it it a group by, i need the last row of each value of a spcific column, in one datatable. did you get me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented in a simple loop using a Dictionary to hold found rows:

```
        var cRows = new Dictionary<string, DataRow>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        foreach (DataRow oRow in oTable.Rows)
        {
            var sKey = oRow["KeyValue"].ToString();

            if (!cRows.ContainsKey(sKey))
            {
                cRows.Add(sKey, oRow);
            }
            else
            {
                cRows[sKey] = oRow;
            }
        }
```

This approach will store the last row for each unique value in the column that you nominate.

To move the selected rows into a new DataTable:

```
        var oNewTable = oTable.Clone();

        foreach (var oRow in cRows.Values)
        {
            oNewTable.Rows.Add(oRow);
        }
```

`Clone` just clones the structure of the current table, not the rows.

Comment: and then i need to transfer the dictionary to datatable?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: yes, also easy. I have updated the answer with the code to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can `GroupBy()` and then select last row with the help of the `Last()` method.

```
var result = from b in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
             group b by b.Field<string>("Your_Column_Name") into g
             select g.Last(); 

DataTable filtered = myDataTable.Clone();
foreach(DataRow row in result)
{
    filtered.ImportRow(row);
}
```

[`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx)  clones the structure of the `DataTable`, including all `DataTable` schemas and constraints.

Comment: i need to take all the columns that existed in these last three rows, does your answer support that please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Yes, I am selecting last row with the Column value.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts a lot, I wish I could accept more than one answer, plus one , many thanks