# c# adding row that already belongs to a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable `DTgraph`, that datatable has a column named `Campaign`. that column could have one of three unique values, which are `IVR, City`, City2`. So the rows are like this:

I have a datatable has data like this format

```
........ IVR........

.........IVR........

**.........IVR........**

.........City1......

.........City1......

**.........City1......**

.........City2......

.........City2......

**.........City2......**
```

I want to take the last row of each unique value for that column, In other words, I want to take the rows that are bold. I did almost everything like this:

```
var cRows = new Dictionary<string, DataRow>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

foreach (DataRow oRow in DTgraph.Rows)
{
    var sKey = oRow["Campaign"].ToString();

    if (!cRows.ContainsKey(sKey))
    {
        cRows.Add(sKey, oRow);
    }
    else
    {
        cRows[sKey] = oRow;
    }
}

var oNewTable = DTgraph.Clone();

foreach (var oRow in cRows.Values)
{
    oNewTable.Rows.Add(oRow);
}
```

As you see, I put the data in dictionary and transferred the dictionary to a datatable at the end.

My problem is that on this line:

```
cRows.Add(sKey, oRow);
```

I get an error:

> The row is already belongs to another datatable

**Note**: I need to solve that exception, I don't need a new way of doing my goal

**Note**: I was wrong, the exception is on this line

```
oNewTable.Rows.Add(oRow);
```

Comment: Taken over from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648984/c-sharp-datatable-select-last-row-on-a-speicfic-condition

Comment: You are making an effort to ensure the keys are unique, but then putting the values in the table, and it complains the values you put in the table aren't unqiue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest I don't 100% understand your question, however to fix the exception:

> The row is already belongs to another datatable.

Change:

```
oNewTable.Rows.Add(oRow);
```

To:

```
oNewTable.ImportRow(oRow);
```

---

Alternatively create a new row and clone the ItemArray.

```
foreach (var oRow in cRows.Values)
{
    var newRow = oNewTable.NewRow();
    newRow.ItemArray = oRow.ItemArray.Clone() as object[];
    oNewTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Comment: i was wrong, i corrected the question, i was wrong on the line that throws the exception, could you check please

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli That is the line I have fixed, did you read the answer?

Comment: I am trying it wait please. the db is on cloud and i am waiting for permission, max 4 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Use `NewRow()` function of the new table and then use `oRow.ItemArray` property to get values from the source row and copy them the newly created row's `ItemArray`. An example would be:

```
Array.Copy(oRow.ItemArray, oNewTable.NewRow().ItemArray, oRow.ItemArray.Length)
```

However, remember that this would not preserve original values and current state from the source row (which I don't think you're using here anyway). If those things matter, go for `ImportRow()` solution which preserves source row's state when copying.

Comment: i was wrong, i corrected the question, i was wrong on the line that throws the exception, could you check please

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: That is the line you need to replace with the code I have written above. Did you try it?

Comment: plus one, i hope i can accept more than answer, many thanks for the efforts . appreciate it